# WinHttp, get proxy settings from Chrome

Tags: c++, http, proxy, winhttp

I'm developping a "web-service" (http/https encapsulation). I developped my client with WinHttp.lib and my server with HttpServer Api.

My client system has proxy to go out of its system. Thanks to WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser, i get proxy setting and the communication runs. But, **how can i get the proxy settings from Chrome or Mozilla?**

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure Chrome shares proxy settings with IE. FireFox has its own settings store; I suppose you could try and dig proxy settings out of prefs.js

Comment: WinHttp Communication uses only Internet Explorer?

Comment: WinHTTP is independent from Internet Explorer - neither uses the other.

Comment: Yes, i get proxy setting correctly by chrome, but, when i start my communication (my proxy need authentification), if the passord is not in Internet Explorer i have 407 Http Response. I would like to use chrome for my communication

Comment: Ok, it's just to be sure :). And do you know librairy to communicate via Chrome?

Comment: No I do not. I don't believe Chrome provides an API for external applications (it does provide an API for Chrome extensions and Chrome apps; perhaps whatever it is you are trying to do can be implemented as one of those).

Comment: Thank you, so it's the same for Mozilla, it doesn't provide an API for http communication?

Comment: Correct, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: So to do http/https client/server communication, we must use Internet Explorer and cannot use Chrome or Mozilla or other browser?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "use Internet Explorer". Windows operating system provides two HTTP stacks for use by applications - WinInet and WinHttp. Internet Explorer is an application like any other; it happens to be using WinInet. You can choose to use it, too, or use WinHTTP, or implement your own HTTP stack if you are so inclined. FireFox and Chrome chose the latter option.